# In visual-studio-code, How do I copy a part in a row (let's call it "A"), search for a certain part of code ("B"), and replace it with "A"?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need to batch edit several files (so we are talking about a Folder search/replace).
In short, I need to copy a part in a row (let's call it "A"), search for a certain part of code ("B"), and replace it with "A".
Consider that:

1. "B" is always the same across all files to be edited
2. both "A" and "B" are always at the same rows ("B" is the row after "A")
3. both "A" and "B" are always preceded by the same portion of code
4. "A" ends with a dash (that is excluded)

this is how the part of the code looks like:

```
extern string CustomComment = "111012003-BlaBlaBla";  // "111012003" is "A" - "extern string CustomComment = " is always present at the same position
extern int TeeGr = 12345;                             // "12345" is "B" - "extern int TeeGr = " is always present at the same position
```

Consider also that "A" is the first part of the file name

Thank you

Comment: Search and Replace in [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files) document helps you

Comment: Thank you, very useful.
Yet, I did not find what I'm looking for, since what I'm trying to do is actually a copy-search-replace(paste) action across files in the same directory.
With the characteristics I've explained above.
Or maybe I was not able to find the explanation I'm looking for.
If that's the case, please point me in the right direction.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex Search for

```
extern string CustomComment = "([^-]+)([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+extern int TeeGr = ([^;]+)
```

- `extern string CustomComment = "` : literal text preceding A
- `([^-]+)` : capture A - all until a `-`
- `([^\r\n]+)` : capture all until a newline
- `[\r\n]+` : the newline
- `extern int TeeGr =`  : literal text preceding B
- `([^;]+)` : capture B - all until a `;`

Replace with

```
extern string CustomComment = "$1$2\nextern int TeeGr = $1
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, and I think I'm going to learn a lot from it.
Very precious.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @PinoArla If it is a solution for you, you can mark the answer as solved